# Why linker doesn't find my template function declared in class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, linker, android-ndk

Well, the title says everything. I get this message when linking(compilation is successful):

`F:/Android/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/
../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.ex
e: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/hellondk/Player/Renderer.o: in function Renderer::On
SurfaceCreated():jni/Player/Renderer.cpp:63: error: undefined reference to 'void
 GameObject::test<void>()'`

GameObject.h:

```
class GameObject
{
    public:
    ...
    template<typename T> T test();
}
```

GameObject.cpp:

```
template<typename T> T GameObject::test()
{

}
```

Renderer.cpp(using the template):

```
object = new GameObject();
...
object->test<void>(); // error here
```

Comment: Not again... define templates in headers unless you **really** know what you are doing and the implications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must define template functions in a header file, otherwise the compiler won't know where to find the definition and only the declaration, which gives you a linker error like the one you have.

Comment: Here's a nice little page on linking with templates http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl.html It basically goes to describe two different ways of solving it, one of which is the solution above

Answer (score 0):

You declare your template as `test()` but you are trying to call a function called `testas()`.  This may be your problem.  Where is `testas()` defined?

Comment: sorry, copy-paste mistake, fixed.

Comment: Ah, I see the edit, but your error message at the top still states `testas()`.  Is that also a paste error?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that :D. Fixed again...

Comment: Ok, the error message also states that your call to `test()` function is trying to pass in a `ComponentType` as a parameter, but your definition has no parameters.  I've tried your snippet of code on my compiler and it works fine, there must be something else involved that you may have left out.

Comment: Fixed once again... Moved it to header file and now it works fine.